# Que atributo uso para colocar legendas ocultas em HTML(não quero em CSS) para deficientes visuais?

Tags: html, img

Gostaria de colocar uma legenda oculta em uma imagem usando apenas HTML, mas não é o título da imagem quando coloco o mouse em cima, é um atributo da imagem, uma legenda que não aparece para usuários normais, porém quando um deficiente visual está usando uma ferramenta de leitura de texto, o programa ou ferramenta lê essa legenda que o programador colocou e assim ajuda para que o deficiente visual tenha acesso a informação que descreve a imagem.

Comment: Não seria o atributo `alt` o que você procura?

Answer (score 1):

> O `ARIA` é um conjunto de atributos especiais para a acessibilidade,
>   que pode ser adicionado a qualquer linguagem marcação, mas é
>   especialmente adequado para HTML. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA)

O atributo [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute), em especial, é usado para definir um string na tag do elemento atual. Ele pode ser comparado com outros métodos de descrição de imagem no exemplo a seguir:

```html
<img 
  src="//example.com/404.png"
  title="mouse hover" 
  aria-label="screen readers">
<img 
  src="//example.com/404.png"
  alt="erro ao carregar imagem" 
  title="mouse hover" 
  aria-label="screen readers">
<img 
  src="//via.placeholder.com/150x150" 
  alt="erro ao carregar imagem" 
  title="mouse hover" 
  aria-label="screen readers">
```

Percebe-se que:

- `alt` substitue o tradicional ícone de erro quando o `src` é inválido;
- `title` exibe um pequeno texto quando o cursor repousa sobre a imagem; e
- `aria-label` configura um texto a ser processado pelo leitor de tela.

Comment: Não entendi direito qual o objetivo do aria-label, o atributo que precisava era o alt, ele é um dos resposáveis por deixar o site mais acessível:
  (https://tableless.com.br/o-poder-do-atributo-alt/).